# "This program can only be executed on the ASUS computer" (P4G) when starting my ASUS laptop

Tags: asus-laptop

I re-installed Windows 8 on my ASUS UX31E and I've started installing the drivers. Suddenly, I'm getting this error message:

[image: This program can only be executed on the ASUS computer.]

What is wrong? How do I get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **ATK package** is not installed. You need to install **ATKACPI driver and hotkey-related utilities** on your computer, then the error message will disappear.

Comment: Why do you use the word "Probably" if it was the solution?

Comment: There might be another reason but this has always worked for me.

Comment: I am saying that; using the word probably makes this answer sound like a suggestion instead of the solution, suggestions are comments

Comment: Ok. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It will also solve eventual problems with hotkeys not working and laptop not entering sleep/hibernation properly.

Comment: Last update: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win8/ATKPackage/ATKPackage_Win8_64_VER100050.zip (17/10/2016)