# ASUS ATK package not working properly

Tags: drivers, asus-laptop

I have installed latest version of ASUS ATK package, but altough at startup I still get pop up windows saying:

```
P4G:  this program can only be executed on the asus computer atk installed
```

Also my instant key stopped working and keyboard backlights.. I'm sure it's not hardware as lights turn on on startup... I have reinstalled atk package multiple times and it doesn't work..

Comment: This same problem was faced by another user. Here is the [solution](http://superuser.com/questions/820303/this-program-can-only-be-executed-on-the-asus-computer-p4g-when-starting-my).

Comment: No, he didnt have ATK package installed, but I have

Comment: Do you have the other hotkey related utilies installed?